# How to set MAILTO in cron using Puppet?

Tags: email, puppet, cron

The expectation was that there would be a `mailto` attribute, but the [this source](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#cron) denies that

> ```
> cron { 'resource title':
>   name        => # (namevar) The symbolic name of the cron job.  This name is 
>   ensure      => # The basic property that the resource should be...
>   command     => # The command to execute in the cron job.  The...
>   environment => # Any environment settings associated with this...
>   hour        => # The hour at which to run the cron job. Optional; 
>   minute      => # The minute at which to run the cron job...
>   month       => # The month of the year.  Optional; if specified...
>   monthday    => # The day of the month on which to run the...
>   provider    => # The specific backend to use for this `cron...
>   special     => # A special value such as 'reboot' or 'annually'...
>   target      => # The name of the crontab file in which the cron...
>   user        => # The user who owns the cron job.  This user must...
>   weekday     => # The weekday on which to run the command...
>   # ...plus any applicable metaparameters.
> }
> ```

The docs does not indicate if mailto is supported, e.g.:

> environment
>
> (Property: This attribute represents concrete state on the target
>   system.)
>
> Any environment settings associated with this cron job. They will be
>   stored between the header and the job in the crontab. There can be no
>   guarantees that other, earlier settings will not also affect a given
>   cron job.
>
> Also, Puppet cannot automatically determine whether an existing,
>   unmanaged environment setting is associated with a given cron job. If
>   you already have cron jobs with environment settings, then Puppet will
>   keep those settings in the same place in the file, but will not
>   associate them with a specific job.
>
> Settings should be specified exactly as they should appear in the
>   crontab, e.g., PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in Puppet type [`cron`](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/cron_core) as referenced in the question has a property named [`environment`](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/cron_core/reference#environment) that can be used to set environment variables for the managed cronjob.

In this case it would look like this, setting the `MAILTO` variable to `foobar` so that output of the cronjob will be mailed to user `foobar`:

```
cron { 'some-cron-job':
  ...
  environment => 'MAILTO=foobar',
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a module from puppet forge to manage cron and add environment variables to the cron job. I've used [this one](https://forge.puppet.com/torrancew/cron), there may be [others](https://forge.puppet.com/tags/cron?utf-8=%E2%9C%93&sort=&page=1).

You can do this

```
cron::job {
  'mysqlbackup':
    minute      => '40',
    hour        => '2',
    date        => '*',
    month       => '*',
    weekday     => '*',
    user        => 'root',
    command     => 'mysqldump -u root mydb',
    environment => [ 'MAILTO=root', 'PATH="/usr/bin:/bin"' ];
}
```

Which among other things sets the MAILTO and PATH environment variables.

Comment: There is no need to use a special module just to be able to set environment variables for a cron job. The built-in `cron` type, as referenced in the question, has a parameter `environment` for this exact purpose.

Comment: @daff Please transform this comment into an answer so I could accept it

Comment: @daff Confirmed that it works

Comment: @Alfred, ok will do!

Comment: @daff I use that module for other reasons and sadly ASSuMEd that the OP had at least read the docs before posting :(

Comment: @lain I have read the documents, but did not find where to set the mailto parameter. Your answer works as well (+1). If the same outcome is possible using the native cron puppet type then I prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

`cron` sends output to the user running the job. If you want to redirect the mail there are a few options.

- Handle the output and mailing in the script running the job.
- Use an entry in the email aliases file to redirect the output.  This will redirect all the user's mail.
- Use `procmail`, or another program to redirect the message when it is delivered to the user's mailbox.